# Using UITapGestureRecognizer rather than manually calling tapCount

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

I've been checking for multiple taps, whether it is 2 or 10 by simply calling tapCount on any touch:

`[[touches anyObject] tapCount]==2`

This simply checks for a double tap.

It works fine. I'm wondering if there is any particular reason to instead start using `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

It would seem that the `UITapGestureRecognizer` API provides wrappers around the same functionality as just inspecting touches directly, as above. Things like `tapCount` and the number of fingers on the screen don't require `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

For things like swipes, I can see the simplicity in letting UIKit handle recognizing those, as they are harder to code manually, but for a tapCount? Where's the real gain here, what am I missing?

Comment: Less code to have to add to each UIView subclass to get *n*-tap actions. Instead of dealing with the various states (finished, cancelled, right tap count, etc), you have a target/action that is set with a callback when your taps happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gesture recognizers provide for coordination in processing multiple gesture types on the same view.  See the discussion of the state machine in the documentation.

If a tap is the only gesture of interest, you may not find much value, but the architecture comes in handy if you want to coordinate the recognition of taps with other gestures provided either by you or system supplied classes, such as scroll views.  Gesture recognizers are given first crack at touches, so you will need to use this architecture, if you want, for example, to recognize touches in a child of a scroll view, before the scroll view processes them.

The gesture recognizers can also be set to defer recognition, so, for example, the action for a single tap is not called until a double tap has timed out.

In general, the gesture recognizer approach is a good one to adopt because it allows gestures to be managed in a consistent fashion across apps and code sources.  If Apple wanted to add an assistive technology preference that allowed the user to select a longer over which a double tap would be recognized. they could do this without requiring any changes to the code of developers using standard gesture recognizers.

I should add that gesture recognizers can be added directly to your storyboard or nib, so in most cases you only need to code the target action, which could be a time saver in new code.

Answer (score 0):

UITapGestureRecognizer provides a cleaner, easier to use API, but no new functionality. So for your case, no reason.